# What thread is waiting on - not able to find from thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following thread dump for one of applications thread:

```
"Worker-pool-6" #238 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fa9ac03d800 nid=0x276 waiting on condition [0x00007fa9541b5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c69a2c10> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to understand at what condition it is waiting for? I tried to search for those hexa values `0x00007fa9541b5000` and `0x00000006c69a2c10` in entire thread dump but I can't find those hexa values elsewhere.

This thread remains in this condition for ever, so need to understand this. What exactly it is waiting for?

Comment: This is an internal worker pool, waiting for work. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: @Thilo: Any insight how to decipher it?

Comment: @CuriousMind The `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread is waiting for the private `getTask()` method to return with a task to process. As the comment in the source code says: *"Performs blocking or timed wait for a task"*. --- Seems pretty straightforward to me. All you need to do is a minute amount of **research**, i.e. looking at the source code, which any good IDE makes easy.